# Change button to sign out when connected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am making a website with HTML and C# (asp.net).

When you first run the website there is a sign in button, and when you are signing in the "sign in" button changing into "sign out".

I now have a problem when you run the website again: at the start, there is immediately the "sign out" button. I tried this C# code:

```
if (Session["UserId"] != null)
{
    signin.InnerText = "Sign Out";
    string cssClass = string.Empty;
    cssClass = "navbar-btn btn-danger btn right";
    signin.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
}
else
{
    signin.InnerText = "Sign In";
    string cssClass = string.Empty;
    cssClass = "navbar-btn btn-success btn right";
    signin.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
}
```

but it still doesn't work.

Maybe should I ask if window is closed then clear the session? If I should, how can I do that?

Comment: How are you handling sessions? What sets `Session["UserId"]`?

Comment: In my Access data set there is a tab of UserId in the usersTable. If the user connects via the login form , the UserId enters into the session.